# How to prove (-1)*u=-u for all real numbers $u$?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

How can we show that additive inverse of a real number equals the number multiplied by -1, i.e. how can we show that $(-1)*u = -u$ for all  real numbers $u$?

Comment: $0=(1-1)u=\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

$-u$ is the unique additive inverse of $u$. By distributivity we have 
$$(-1)u+u=(-1)u+(1)u=(-1+1)u=0u=0$$
and hence $(-1)u=-u.$ To prove $0u=0$, observe $0u=(0+0)u=0u+0u$ and the additive identity element is unique.

Answer (score 3):

$(-1)*u = (-1)*u + u - u = (-1)*u + (1)*u - u = (-1+1)*u - u = -u$

Comment: Actually this raises another question: why $(-1+1)u=0$? Or shorter: why $0u=0$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&& (1 + (-1)) &= 0 \\
&\implies& (1+(-1))\cdot u &= 0\cdot u = 0\\
&\implies& u + (-1)\cdot u &= 0\\
&\implies& (-u) + (u + (-1)\cdot u) &= -u\\
&\implies& (-u + u) + (-1)\cdot u &= -u\\
&\implies& (-1)\cdot u &= -u
\end{align}

Comment: This seems more of a "from scratch" approach to the rest of the answers. Thanks!